# How do I pass an arbitrary amount of arguments to a for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, arguments

I want to pass items from a dictionary to a for loop, in such a way, that I can pass an arbitrary amount of called dictionary items to it.

I've tried searching for it all day yesterday, yet I could not find an answer that I understood.

Here's the code:

```
import itertools

categories = {
    "cat1": ["House Cat", "Lion"],
    "cat2": ["House", "Apartment", "Cellar"],
    "cat3": ["Germany", "England", "USA", "Brazil"]
}

def find_unique_combinations(*args):
    args = args
    for combination in itertools.product(args):
        print(combination)

find_unique_combinations(categories["cat1"], categories["cat2"])
```

I'm also being given this error:

```
TypeError: Required argument 'r' (pos 2) not found
```

Comment: Did you read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)?  What do you intend `itertools.combinations(args)` to do?

Comment: You searched for it all day and, with an error message like that, didn't look at the documentation to see what kind of arguments it takes?

Comment: Why are you using `itertools.combinations` here? Also, what do you want to do?

Comment: @BrenBarn I meant to use itertools.product(...), sorry.

Comment: I'm also puzzled by `args = args`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass an arbitrary number of arguments to combinations() because it is written to take an iterable. The r argument is to denote what length of combination you want from your iterable.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations